# any one can explain the color histogram code?

Tags: python, image-processing, multidimensional-array, computer-vision, histogram

i have copied code of color histogram, but i don't understand about the used of range 0,15 and the value of 17. anyone can explain me?

here the code:

```
# Colour Histogram
Blue = cv2.calcHist([img], [0], None, [256], [0,256])
Green = cv2.calcHist([img], [1], None, [256], [0,256])
Red = cv2.calcHist([img], [2], None, [256], [0,256])
result_R = [i for i in range(0,15)]
result_G = [i for i in range(0,15)]
result_B = [i for i in range(0,15)]
start = 0
end = 17
for i in range(0,15):
     r = np.sum(Red[start:end])
     g = np.sum(Green[start:end])
     b = np.sum(Blue[start:end])
     start = end
     end = end + 17
     result_R[i] = r
     result_G[i] = g
     result_B[i] = b
```

Comment: Might be the width of the image..?

Comment: The usual range of color values is 0 to 255. 255 = 17 * 15.

Comment: based on `result_R[i] = r` I think the list comprehension is just to initialize the list to the right size, it is really confusing code.

Comment: it's awful code. it has multiple off-by-one errors. -- don't just ask "explain this code to me". show that you *tried* to understand it yourself. explain what you *do* understand. this is a lazy question.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I notice is that `result_R` (and `g` and `b`) are being initialized to lists, but inside the loop it is assigning an element of the list so the initial values are being overridden.

So it would be just as valid to start with empty lists and `.append` the new values with each loop so lets start there:

```py
# Colour Histogram
Blue = cv2.calcHist([img], [0], None, [256], [0,256])
Green = cv2.calcHist([img], [1], None, [256], [0,256])
Red = cv2.calcHist([img], [2], None, [256], [0,256])
result_R = [] # edited
result_G = [] # edited
result_B = [] # edited
start = 0
end = 17
for i in range(0,15):
     r = np.sum(Red[start:end])
     g = np.sum(Green[start:end])
     b = np.sum(Blue[start:end])
     start = end
     end = end + 17
     result_R.append(r) # edited
     result_G.append(g) # edited
     result_B.append(b) # edited
```

The next thing I notice is that `start` and `end` are being modified each loop and `i` is no longer being used inside the loop so we can simplify the management of those indices with the loop variable:

```py
# Colour Histogram
Blue = cv2.calcHist([img], [0], None, [256], [0,256])
Green = cv2.calcHist([img], [1], None, [256], [0,256])
Red = cv2.calcHist([img], [2], None, [256], [0,256])
result_R = []
result_G = []
result_B = []
STEP = 17
for start in range(0,255, STEP): # starting at 0 and in steps of 17 up to 256
     end = start+STEP # equivelent to the start of the next loop
     r = np.sum(Red[start:end])
     g = np.sum(Green[start:end])
     b = np.sum(Blue[start:end])
     result_R.append(r)
     result_G.append(g)
     result_B.append(b)
```

This makes the code easier to understand but doesn't quite explain where the `15` and `17` came from, based on the `np.sum` the distance between the `start` and `end` represents the bin size so `15` ends up being the number of bins since `15*17=255` although I'm not totally sure, by using `end=255` it actually omits the last element of the sequence so if an image was all pitch white I'd expect the resulting histogram to be completely empty and I suspect that is a bug with the binning algorithm.